# Delaying email being sent out on all devices

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange, office365

We use Office 365 and are looking for a way to delay email so that it only gets sent out at a certain time of day.

I see you can do this on [Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-026af69f-c287-490a-a72f-6c65793744ba) but what about on the server side for mobile devices and more?

Comment: N.B. In some cases the email is sent immediately, relying on the mailserver to delay forwarding of the message. Not all mailservers respect that delay flag.

Comment: Can you give us more infos why you wish to perform that? Depending on these infos we might then help and give you more infos.